# Modify SQL Query in SSRS at runtime

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

Is there a way to modify the SQL Query at runtime using some code?  I have a situation where I have an ASP.NET application and I want to pass data to a SSRS report without adding parameters.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a dataset from ASP.NET to a ReportViewer control.

```
DataSet ds = GetDataSet();
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = “ReportServer/myReport.rdlc”;
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(”ds”, ds.Tables[0]));
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.  I am getting the following error message:

Comment: I am getting an error for this line:  DataSet ds = GetDataSet();  Error 1 The name 'GetDataSet' does not exist in the current context

Comment: The GetDataSet method is just a fake filler.  You need to create a method that is responsible for obtaining a DataSet that can be passed to the report viewer.

Comment: I need to be able to change the sql query inside the ssrs report at runtime.  What is the best way to do that?  I was able to do that in Crystal Report but not SSRS report.  It is very frustrating.

Comment: My recommendation is not to change the query in the SSRS report.  Instead, populate you query in code with a DataSet, and then send that DataSet to the SSRS report.  This way no query is needed inside the SSRS report, it is just acting as a host.  Another option is to use dynamic sql inside a stored procedure that is called by your SSRS report, in order to make it dynamic.

Comment: dretzlaff17, can you send me an code example on how to populate by query in code with a dataset?

Comment: Here is a link to reference on how to populate a DataSet.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z(VS.71).aspx